# Bootstrap navbar transparent when closed, colored when open

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, responsive

I'm creating a navbar for a homepage with bootstrap. 
The background color from the navbar is grey on desktop. When I switch to mobile, a burger menu appears and opens the navbar via a dropwdown on tap.

Actually on a mobile device the navbar with the menu button is available, but the background is grey. When I make it transparent, it look great but when I open the menu, the dropdown is also transparent.

How can I get the background transparent when the menu is closed and grey when it's open?

Little code snippet if needed:

```
<nav class="navbar header navbar-expand-lg navbar-neptun bg-neptun">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row tablet_header" style="justify-content: center;">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12 topNavigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed header_button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          &#9776;
        </button>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

[image: problem]

Comment: Reading again through your question it is not very clear which part of the navbar you actually want to make transparent. Are you talking about the main horizontal bar (for making it transparent)? Or is it about the part that slides down when the user clicks on the toggle? In other words, are you only talking about the navbar when the hamburger button is visible?

Comment: Look at the image: this is the actual navbar on a mobile device. This should be transparent not grey. When the user clicks the button, the navbar is transparent but then the background should be grey.
On desktop it should always be grey.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly: Normally, you want the navbar background to be transparent but when the user clicks the button you want the navbar background to turn grey. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I want for mobile!

Comment: Hmm... and what should happen when the navbar is NOT collapsed to a hamburger button for mobile screens?

Comment: On a mobile device, the navigation bar should be transparent and only the burger menu should be displayed. When the user clicks on the burger menu, the navigation bar should turn gray and show the menu. If it is closed again, it should become transparent again and the menu disappears. On a desktop, the background should remain gray throughout.